# Bad Request (400) https://vec01.maps.yandex.net/tiles, при загрузке карты маленького размера

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Одна и та же карта, на десктопе грузится отлично. Все события карты работают идеально.

Если же я меняю размер экрана (например ширина 320px) и перезагружаю страницу,  либо открываю страницу на мобиле, то при событии клика на карте, в консоли получаю

```
GET https://vec01.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=mapj&v=18.08.27-0&x=NaN&y=NaN&z=12&scale=1&lang=ru_RU&callback=x_NaN_y_NaN_z_12_l_mapj 400 (Bad Request)
```

Метка появляется, но через секунду исчезает.

Чем это может быть обусловлено? Ранее такой проблемы не замечал, с тем же кодом вывода карты...

Заранее спасибо!

Вот пример [ссылка](http://bs.segaweb.ru/content/test-map). Код взят отсюда [ссылка](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode/). При нормальном режиме отображения сайта, балун нормально открывается и показывает координаты. Если же при мобильном отображении, то ломается...

Comment: Предоставьте, пожалуйста, пример где это можно посмотреть. Например на http://jsfiddle.net/1zj2rbwu/

Comment: Из параметров запроса я вижу, что у вас запрос с невалидными координатами (NaN вместо номера тайла). Обычно это бывает, когда выставляется неправильный центр или границы карты, например, передаётся null или координаты в неверном формате.

Comment: @se0ga На jsfiddle не получается воспроизвести проблему, т.к. там нет возможности мобильного отображения...

Comment: @Reni Видимо проблема в этом. Я заметил, что событие клик по карте (при мобильном отображении) срабатывает два раза. При чем первый раз координаты нормальные приходят, а второй раз (с небольшой задержкой) [NaN, NaN]. В этом и есть, видимо, причина моей проблемы...

Странно, почему только при мобильном отображении такое происходит...

Comment: ну если вы предоставите пример я смогу его открыть на мобильном устройстве)

Comment: @se0ga Вот пример ([ссылка](http://bs.segaweb.ru/content/test-map)). 
Код взят отсюда [ссылка](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode/)

При нормальном режиме отображения сайта, балун нормально открывается и показывает координаты. Если же при мобильном отображении, то ломается...

Comment: Воспроизвести не могу. "Если же я меняю размер экрана (например ширина 320px) и перезагружаю страницу" правильно ли я понимаю что проблема воспроизводится на десктопе? В каком браузере? Можете ли предоставить видео воспроизведения проблемы?

Comment: @se0ga Да, проблему можно воспроизвести на десктопе. Я тестирую в браузере Google Chrome, но уверен что и на firefox возможно. 

В Chrome нужно открыть панель разработчика (Ctrl+Shift+I), затем мобильный вид (Ctrl+Shift+M)

Вот скрин с проблемой
[https://ibb.co/iJVcYU](https://ibb.co/iJVcYU)

Comment: Вы сказали что проблема в том что метка пропадает и в консоли ошибка "GET https://vec01...". На скрине вижу метку и ошибка совершенно другая. В чём проявления вашей проблемы?

Comment: Пришлите, пожалуйста, текстом ошибки, которые у вас в консоли. Попробуйте воспроизвести в другом браузере, например Firefox проблема по-прежнему воспроизводится?

Comment: @se0ga Если уменьшить эркан (например до 320px) не перезагружая страницу ошибка следующая:
`GET https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/search//v2/?callback=id_15355510021875362900&text=55.632625246234404%2C37.611106671875&format=json&rspn=0&lang=ru_RU&token=7703fc2eb468a9184360eafe6d41a40d&type=geo&properties=addressdetails&geocoder_sco=latlong&origin=jsapi2Geocoder&sign=4214227315 401 (Unauthorized)`

Если перезагрузить страницу с изначально маленьким экраном, то ошибка другая:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'distance' of null`
[https://ibb.co/cqjciU](https://ibb.co/cqjciU)

Comment: @se0ga
Это на чистой карте, тестировал даже на чистом HTML на другом домене, все те же ошибки при мобильном отображении. Да, при такой реализации метка остается, но ошибки...

В моей же реализации, как я писал выше, метка вообще исчезает, но проблема я думаю взаимосвязана...

Comment: Нет ли у Вас возможности взять код отсюда [https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode/](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode/) и просто протестировать его при мобильном отображении страницы?

Comment: @se0ga Проверил в firefox, там такой проблемы нет.

Comment: "Если уменьшить эркан (например до 320px) не перезагружая страницу ошибка следующая: GET https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/search//v2/?callback=id_15355510021875362900&text=55.632625246234404%2C37.611106671875&format=json&rspn=0&lang=ru_RU&token=7703fc2eb468a9184360eafe6d41a40d&type=geo&properties=addressdetails&geocoder_sco=latlong&origin=jsapi2Geocoder&sign=4214227315 401 (Unauthorized)" если вы уменьшаете карту в мобильном отображении в хроме, то это невалидный кейс. Хром, что-то меняет в процессе изменения размеров в режиме тестирования. Всегда нужно перезагружать страницу.

Comment: В чистом кейсе в мобильном отображении не воспроизводится. Воспроизводится только на вашем сайте так как там есть разные скрипты. Если отключить uikit то проблема перестаёт воспроизводиться.

Comment: @se0ga Спасибо за помощь. Буду ковырять uikit ((